# Cover with color an area between two figures (layers)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to show that part and be able to color it, but I don't know how is it possible to do it in Adobe Illustrator.

[image: What I want to do]

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw two overlapping rectangles, and select both
2. Open the Pathfinder
3. Hit the Divide button, then Ungroup
4. Select the square in the centre, and change its fill colour

[image]